# What is the purpose of resting non yeast flour dough?

Tags: dough, flour, flour-tortilla

When making something like flour tortillas, which don't call for yeast in the dough, it's called for to have the dough rest for about an hour before forming to a tortilla and cooking. What is the purpose of resting a flour dough without yeast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flour is essentially dried ground wheat, and when you mix it with water, it takes a long time for the flour to absorb water and soften.  This is necessary for the gluten to have a chance to connect, so that you have a streachy dough.

Answer (score 3):

During the so-called autolyse step, [proteases go to work snipping up the gluten](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jsfa.2740220208/full):

> Experimental evidence has been obtained to support the hypothesis that
>   gluten softening is a result of peptide bond scission catalysed by
>   proteolytic enzymes. Extensive softening of gluten is observed even
>   though very few peptide bonds are broken. These effects will probably
>   be more noticeable if the wheat from which the flour is milled has
>   begun to germinate.

Redman, D. G. (1971). Softening of gluten by wheat proteases. Journal of the Science of Food and Agriculture, 22(2), 75-78.